# How can I pass data to Python via node.js and python-shell module?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, electron

I am writing a simple program for electron. I understood how to receive data, but how to transfer it from js to python I cannot understand (((

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can package the data as a JSON string and send it to Python.
A JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a standardized way to describe a JavaScript object. It is formatted as `{key : value}` and you can nest objects in objects like `{key_main : {key0 : value0, key1 : value1}}` and so on.
There is a ES6 function to generate JSON string.

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

And a parser to get back the object from a JSON string.

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

Python has its built in JSON stringify and parse functions too in the json package.

```
import json
json.loads(string)
json.dumps(obj)
```

would be the equivalent parse and stringify in that order. Read more on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

This would be the standard way to exchange data interplatform.